# Avoiding cycle of dependencies between classes via static field initializers

Tags: typescript

I have some building objects for a game calculator that i'm making. Each building object has a requirements array so that you can easily access the requirements at a given level.

The problem is that many of the buildings are requirements for the buildings that they require (at different levels). And as I have come to discover a building (building A) cannot have building B in its static requirements array if building B has it in its own static requirements array.

For example:

```
export class Walls implements Building {

static requirements = [null, [new Keep(1)], [null], [null], [null],
    [null], [null], [null], [null], [null],
    [null], [null], [null], [null], [null],
    [null], [null], [null], [null], [null],
    [null], [null], [null], [null], [null]
];

...
```

Will return an error

> TypeError: Keep_1.Keep is not a constructor

If Keep has the following:

export class Keep implements Building {

```
static requirements = [null, [new Walls(1)], [new Walls(2)], [new Walls(3)], [new Walls(4)],
    [new Walls(5)], [new Walls(6)], [new Walls(7)], [new Walls(8)], [new Walls(9)],
    [new Walls(10)], [new Walls(11)], [new Walls(12)], [new Walls(13)], [new Walls(14)],
    [new Walls(15)], [new Walls(16)], [new Walls(17)], [new Walls(18)], [new Walls(19)],
    [new Walls(20)], [new Walls(21)], [new Walls(22)], [new Walls(23)], [new Walls(24)]
];

...
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, whichever class loads first is going to try to instantiate the other class, which doesn't exist yet.  You could move the code to initialize the `requirements` of each class into a static method of the class and call all of these methods in a single pass after all classes are loaded.  Or each class could have a static `getRequirements` method that initializes the `requirements` field the first time it is called, and as long as nothing calls `getRequirements` until after all classes are loaded, you'll be fine; this way you don't have to manually invoke the initialization pass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!